# md5sum warning about formatted lines

Tags: files, hashsum, checksum, integrity

I am trying to validate a file using the following command:

```
$ md5sum myfile_v2.1.ova -c myfile_v2.1.md5 
md5sum: myfile_v2.1.ova: no properly formatted MD5 checksum lines found
myfile_v2.1.ova: OK
```

The exit status code seems to be `1`

```
$ echo $?
1
```

However when reading the `help` for the `md5sum` command, `strict` mode (which fails upon formatting issues`) should be explicitly enabled;

```
$ md5sum --help | grep -- --strict
      --strict         exit non-zero for improperly formatted checksum lines
```

Why on top of all that I get an `OK` about the file?

Comment: Does the file have a trailing newline?

Comment: how can I check this?

Comment: Run `od -c` on the md5 file and see if the last character is a `\n`

Comment: yep, it is a `\n`

Comment: Thanks for posting this question - I made the same silly mistake.  TLDR: `md5sum -c` treats all files passed as checksum lists, and it uses those lists to work out what files it should actually be checking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct way to verify checksums in an MD5 checksum file is

```
$ md5sum -c file.md5
```

In your case:

```
$ md5sum -c myfile_v2.1.md5
```

This will read the pathname and checksums in the MD5 file and check them against the corresponding files on disk.

---

Your command line:

```
md5sum myfile_v2.1.ova -c myfile_v2.1.md5
```

This is equivalent of

```
md5sum -c myfile_v2.1.ova myfile_v2.1.md5
```

(due to the way some GNU utilities move command line options to the start of the argument list).  This means "check the signatures found in these two MD5 checksum files".  Since the first file isn't an MD5 checksum file, it complains.

Also note that it correctly verifies one checksum from the MD5 file.